# How to test the revert for 'call' function with Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, chai, ethers.js, hardhat

I would like to have 100% code coverage but one function is giving trouble ...

```js
(bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
```

How to force the boolean 'sent' to false ?

Stack : hardhat, solidity, ethers.js, chai.js

I tried to modify the balance of the address which must pay :

```
await network.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [
 "...address...",
 "0x1000"
]);
```

But i don't go to the require, i've got this error :

`sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx`

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
```

> *How to force the boolean 'sent' to false ?*

The first value becomes `false` when the transfer fails.

For example when the recipient is a contract that doesn't implement the `receive()` nor `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions).

So you can have a mock contract that always rejects all native transfers, and assign it as the `to` address.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract FailingRecipient {}
```